# Is it normal to use "Indian" as a noun?

Tags: word-choice

When talking about someone from India, rather than a Native American, is it normal to use "Indian" as a noun?

For example, "The shop-keeper was an Indian."

The person using this word is probably learning American English.

Comment: Is there any particular dialect you are interested in? There may be differences in usage in different parts of the world.

Comment: @choster thanks - I've edited the question to say the person is probably learning American English.

Comment: Equivalent question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9641/what-would-you-call-a-person-from-india

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question! Let the *native speakers* shed more light on it but being an Indian, I'd like to express my views here.

*"Is it normal to use "Indian" as a noun."* -That's absolutely fine to **me.** And, I'm an Indian!

Commonly, we come across *Native* used with *American.* I think that's because when you say *Native American* it implies to a particular group of people.

> [Native American (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/NATIVEAMERICAN) - Any member of the peoples living in North or South America **before the Europeans arrived.**

The US has diversified history (and still going on?) of lot of immigrants from several *continents*.

However, India does not show those many (frequent?) migrations from several **continents** (maybe, there are many who migrate but then they are from nearby **countries** like Nepal, Bangladesh etc.).

Referring to *an Indian* as *an Indian* is okay. In fact, being an Indian, if you call me a *native Indian*, it will sound strange to me.

Note: This is interesting. In [a survey conducted in 1995](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States), most Native Americans referred to themselves as *American Indians* or simply **Indians.**

Comment: I have indeed not met anyone from India so far who seemed to think it strange or who used any alternative to the designation "Indian" for someone from India. Honestly, I think it would be strange to look for an alternative, simply because of some mix-up in the naming of completely unrelated people on the other side of the world :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's normal, including in the sentence you provided.  A little more often, that sentence would be

> The shopkeeper was Indian.

However either form is normal.